# Align elements in a figure

Tags: html, css, image, figure

I've got a problem with my HW. I cant align 2 elements on the left side https://jsfiddle.net/tkjxLfjy/  This is the code and i tried things like `float:left` but didn't work... So can you help me to put the meter and the text under the picture (the black sqare)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

> Elements after a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this,
>   use the clear property.

Add `Clear:both` to the `div`. The `image` has `float:left` so the next elements sit behind that.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/tkjxLfjy/2/)

```
figure div
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `float:left` and add `display: block` to the image

Basically `display: block` *reserve* the whole line for the element, so that no other element set beside it, unless it's *positioned*.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkjxLfjy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You should try like like this-

```css
.clr{
  clear:both
}
body {
 font-family: serif;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#container {
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 height: 280px;
 background-color: pink;
}
.header {
text-align: center;
position:relative;
top: 15px;
}
/* Figure one */
figure{
 float: left;
}
img {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: black;
 
}

meter {
 width: 90px;
}
.meter-col{
 float: left;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="header">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
 </div>
  
 <figure>
  <figcaption>User: Kent</figcaption>
  <img src="avatar.png" />
 </figure>
 <div class="meter-col">
  <div>Profile completed: 60%</div>
  <meter value="60" min="0" max="100">2 out of 10</meter>
 </div>
    <div class="clr"></div> 
</div>
```

May it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
    </div>
    <figure>
        <figcaption>User: Kent</figcaption>
        <img src="avatar.png" />
        <div>
        Profile completed: 60%
        <meter value="60" min="0" max="100">2 out of 10</meter>
        </div>
    </figure>

</div>
```

No need of other changing 'cause the  tag has a default "block" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I changed a few things around. I also updated a few things to HTML5 (preferred). I changed everything to display block and changed the div that all of that lives in to float: left. JS fiddle link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/tkjxLfjy/6/

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <header>
   <h2>Profile</h2>
  </header>
<figure>
 <figcaption>User: Kent</figcaption>
 <img src="avatar.png" />
 <label for="meter">Profile completed: 60%</label>
 <meter name="meter" value="60" min="0" max="100">2 out of 10</meter>
</figure>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: serif;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 650px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 280px;
    background-color: pink;
    float: left;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top: 15px;
}
/* Figure one */
 img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
}
meter {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}
```